# Cannot load Jupyter Lab after installing "jupyter-markdown" extension

Tags: python, markdown, jupyter-lab

I have just installed Jupyter Lab via `pip install`. It works well until I installed "jupyter-markdown" extension via `pip install jupyter-markdown`.

Now I cannot load Jupyter Lab. I get the following error:

```
[W 2023-11-09 22:59:30.662 ServerApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings?1699567170458 (::1): Schema not found: C:/Users/ephra/miniconda3/envs/md/share/jupyter/lab/schemas\@datalayer/jupyter-admin\plugin.json
[W 2023-11-09 22:59:30.663 LabApp] wrote error: 'Schema not found: C:/Users/ephra/miniconda3/envs/md/share/jupyter/lab/schemas\\@datalayer/jupyter-admin\\plugin.json'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ephra\miniconda3\envs\md\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1784, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\ephra\miniconda3\envs\md\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 3290, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\ephra\miniconda3\envs\md\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\settings_handler.py", line 57, in get
        result, warnings = get_settings(
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\ephra\miniconda3\envs\md\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\settings_utils.py", line 386, in get_settings
        settings_list, warnings = _list_settings(
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\ephra\miniconda3\envs\md\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\settings_utils.py", line 211, in _list_settings
        schema, version = _get_schema(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\ephra\miniconda3\envs\md\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\settings_utils.py", line 55, in _get_schema
        raise web.HTTPError(404, notfound_error % path)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Schema not found: C:/Users/ephra/miniconda3/envs/md/share/jupyter/lab/schemas\@datalayer/jupyter-admin\plugin.json)
[W 2023-11-09 22:59:30.665 LabApp] 404 GET /lab/api/settings?1699567170458 (a8be64fc149d42c2b38ccd8d38f052f5@::1) 100.08ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
```

I can remove the virtual environment and recreate the venv and reinstall Jupyter Lab. My question is to know if there is a way of installing "jupyter-markdown" extension and use it in Jupyter Lab. I get the same error if I install the `jupyter-markdown` extension via Jupyter Lab extension tab.

I use Windows 11, python 3.11.0

Comment: What is this extension? If does not ring a bell. What do you need it for (I mean markdown is naively supported by JupyterLab)? Did you try reporting this to extension author?

Comment: @krassowski: it was the extension "jupyterlab-imarkdown". I have now installed "jupyterlab_myst" instead. I am having now some issue when exporting to pdf format. I have reported the issue to the author in github. See: 
https://github.com/executablebooks/jupyterlab-myst/issues/194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed `jupyterlab_myst` extension instead.